# Trouble excluding class from jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that scrambles letters based on shuffleLetters.js. It's working great, but I can't seem to exclude classes that are nested in the class that I'm targeting.

So I want to scramble the characters in my menu items. So I give them a class of `.shuffle` and call the function like so:

```
$(function(){
    var container = $(".shuffle")
    container.shuffleLetters();
});
```

Where .shuffleLetters engages the plugin. The problem is that it's scrambling all the characters that are nested within that menu item, which I don't want.

I've read about the `.not` method, but can't get it to work properly.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<li class="shuffle">title
    <li class="no-shuffle">sub-title
    </li>
</li>
```

then I'm writing my js like so (or every possible variation of):

```
$(function(){
    var container = $(".shuffle").not('.no-shuffle')
    container.shuffleLetters();
});
```

This is not working though.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, racking my brain for hours.

as always, thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's the [shuffleLetters.js](https://code.google.com/p/miqdad-test/source/browse/trunk/my+files/js/jquery.shuffleLetters.js?r=42):

```
(function($){

    $.fn.shuffleLetters = function(prop){

        var options = $.extend({
            "step"      : 8,            // How many times should the letters be changed
            "fps"       : 25,           // Frames Per Second
            "text"      : "",           // Use this text instead of the contents
            "callback"  : function(){}  // Run once the animation is complete
        },prop)

        return this.each(function(){

            var el = $(this),
                str = "";


            // Preventing parallel animations using a flag;

            if(el.data('animated')){
                return true;
            }

            el.data('animated',true);


            if(options.text) {
                str = options.text.split('');
            }
            else {
                str = el.text().split('');
            }

            // The types array holds the type for each character;
            // Letters holds the positions of non-space characters;

            var types = [],
                letters = [];

            // Looping through all the chars of the string

            for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

                var ch = str[i];

                if(ch == " "){
                    types[i] = "space";
                    continue;
                }
                else if(/[a-z]/.test(ch)){
                    types[i] = "lowerLetter";
                }
                else if(/[A-Z]/.test(ch)){
                    types[i] = "upperLetter";
                }
                else {
                    types[i] = "symbol";
                }

                letters.push(i);
            }

            el.html("");            

            // Self executing named function expression:

            (function shuffle(start){

                // This code is run options.fps times per second
                // and updates the contents of the page element

                var i,
                    len = letters.length, 
                    strCopy = str.slice(0); // Fresh copy of the string

                if(start>len){

                    // The animation is complete. Updating the
                    // flag and triggering the callback;

                    el.data('animated',false);
                    options.callback(el);
                    return;
                }

                // All the work gets done here
                for(i=Math.max(start,0); i < len; i++){

                    // The start argument and options.step limit
                    // the characters we will be working on at once

                    if( i < start+options.step){
                        // Generate a random character at thsi position
                        strCopy[letters[i]] = randomChar(types[letters[i]]);
                    }
                    else {
                        strCopy[letters[i]] = "";
                    }
                }

                el.text(strCopy.join(""));

                setTimeout(function(){

                    shuffle(start+1);

                },1000/options.fps);

            })(-options.step);


        });
    };

    function randomChar(type){
        var pool = "";

        if (type == "lowerLetter"){
            pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        }
        else if (type == "upperLetter"){
            pool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        }
        else if (type == "symbol"){
            pool = ",.?/\\(^)![]{}*&^%$#'\"";
        }

        var arr = pool.split('');
        return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can include _"function that scrambles letters based on shuffleLetters.js"_  Question ? , create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Mine showing us how the `shuffleLetters()` function is defined so we can reproduce your example? Also note you want your `<li>` to be inside `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: Should I include the plugin.js?

Comment: _"Should I include the plugin.js?"_ Yes

Comment: added that .js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping text node "title" in `.shuffle` `li` within `span` element

```js
(function($){

    $.fn.shuffleLetters = function(prop){

        var options = $.extend({
            "step"      : 8,            // How many times should the letters be changed
            "fps"       : 25,           // Frames Per Second
            "text"      : "",           // Use this text instead of the contents
            "callback"  : function(){}  // Run once the animation is complete
        },prop)

        return this.each(function(){

            var el = $(this),
                str = "";


            // Preventing parallel animations using a flag;

            if(el.data('animated')){
                return true;
            }

            el.data('animated',true);


            if(options.text) {
                str = options.text.split('');
            }
            else {
                str = el.text().split('');
            }

            // The types array holds the type for each character;
            // Letters holds the positions of non-space characters;

            var types = [],
                letters = [];

            // Looping through all the chars of the string

            for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

                var ch = str[i];

                if(ch == " "){
                    types[i] = "space";
                    continue;
                }
                else if(/[a-z]/.test(ch)){
                    types[i] = "lowerLetter";
                }
                else if(/[A-Z]/.test(ch)){
                    types[i] = "upperLetter";
                }
                else {
                    types[i] = "symbol";
                }

                letters.push(i);
            }

            el.html("");            

            // Self executing named function expression:

            (function shuffle(start){

                // This code is run options.fps times per second
                // and updates the contents of the page element

                var i,
                    len = letters.length, 
                    strCopy = str.slice(0); // Fresh copy of the string

                if(start>len){

                    // The animation is complete. Updating the
                    // flag and triggering the callback;

                    el.data('animated',false);
                    options.callback(el);
                    return;
                }

                // All the work gets done here
                for(i=Math.max(start,0); i < len; i++){

                    // The start argument and options.step limit
                    // the characters we will be working on at once

                    if( i < start+options.step){
                        // Generate a random character at thsi position
                        strCopy[letters[i]] = randomChar(types[letters[i]]);
                    }
                    else {
                        strCopy[letters[i]] = "";
                    }
                }

                el.text(strCopy.join(""));

                setTimeout(function(){

                    shuffle(start+1);

                },1000/options.fps);

            })(-options.step);


        });
    };

    function randomChar(type){
        var pool = "";

        if (type == "lowerLetter"){
            pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
        }
        else if (type == "upperLetter"){
            pool = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        }
        else if (type == "symbol"){
            pool = ",.?/\\(^)![]{}*&^%$#'\"";
        }

        var arr = pool.split('');
        return arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
    }

})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    var container = $(".shuffle span:first")
    container.shuffleLetters();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
<li class="shuffle"><span>title</span>
  <ul>
    <li class="no-shuffle">sub-title
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually I spoke too soon, I should have mentioned that there's more than one menu item in the nav that I wanted to apply this to... All top level menu items, to be exact. This seems to only apply the effect to the first list item in the nav - though has successfully stopped it from cycling through all the nested list items.

Comment: I just removed the `:first` and it worked perfectly, thanks again!